# Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I am trying to setup a spring boot application. I have a docker container running MySQL and I am trying to configure FlywayDB. I have been following the flyway [guide](https://flywaydb.org/), but whenever I try to run the app I keep getting a monster exception.

```
2020-06-13 12:55:19.272 ERROR 17823 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Detected failed migration to version 1 (create user table)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at io.shopik.messanger.MessangerApplication.main(MessangerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Detected failed migration to version 1 (create user table)

    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:285) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:74) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:167) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:159) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:530) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:159) ~[flyway-core-6.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2020-06-13 12:55:19.275  WARN 17823 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:81) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:67) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:167) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at io.shopik.messanger.MessangerApplication.main(MessangerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:456) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been looking up tutorials online, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_flyway_database.htm). I have also looked up this site for help and found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318159/beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-with-name-flywayinitializer). But none of this is helping me sort my issue and getting the app started!

I just created a very basic app to get it started, but here's what I have done so far.

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: messanger
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

**application.properties**

```
## This is important
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/messanger?useSSL=false&autoreconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**V1__create_user_table.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**MessangerApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MessangerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessangerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Couple of notes, the docker container can be accessable as I am accessing it from MySQL Workbench.
I have seen on some places that my problem is with the SQL in my .sql file, other places say it's a config issue. Having no luck getting anywhere with this

Answer (score 4):

After days of trying to solve this problem, and then writing this question, I find the answer an hour later!

The issue I had was I kept editing the sql file and flyway had a different checksum when trying to run it, noticed it was different and blew up. Deleting the DB and recreating it solved the problem for me

Comment: just by deleting the flyway schema history table should do the work too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove dependency from **flyway**
2. Remove all configuration flyway **application.properties**
3. DROP your table
4. Run (again) Configure (again)