# How to compose Docker with Integration Testing

Tags: java, docker, integration-testing, flyway

I downloaded Docker and then run Integration Tests in my Intelij Idea written on Java.
And each integration test had the same problem :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.2
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.3
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.4
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.5
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 2.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 3.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 3.2
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 9.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 10.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 10.2
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 11.1
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 11.2
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 11.3
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 11.4
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 11.5
```

How can it be fix?

Comment: Did you checked this already ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318159/beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-with-name-flywayinitializer

Comment: @Tamil.S It doesn't help. I have a little bit another problem as I understand..